# Change VS Code indent guides to showing what indentation the current line starts

Tags: visual-studio-code

How it is right now:

```
<html>
|   <h[]ead>
|       ...
|       ...
|       ...
|   </head>
|
|   <body>
|       ...
|   </body>
|
</html>
```

Where `[]` is the cursor position and `|` is the highlighted indentation guideline

What I'm looking for:

```
<html>
    <h[]ead>
    |   ...
    |   ...
    |   ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...
    </body>

</html>
```

Any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in v1.43 for most cases.  See [Move indent right one when the highlighted line is a scope start/end](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/77762#) :

> Previously, the indent was always to the left of the current line.
>   While this logic was easier to implement, it is inconsistent with the
>   behavior expected. This commit changes it to select the scope (or a
>   rough proxy of that), rather than the line's indent. This is not a
>   complete fix for #49342, as this does not add support to semantic
>   detection, however, this will work in probably 90% of the cases, and
>   is a relatively straightforward fix.

[image: move indent guide]